# Interact with multiple contracts

Tags: nearprotocol

I have a situation where a set of two contracts is deployed to two addresses, for example:

```
share.ysn-1_0_0.ysn.testnet
market.share.ysn-1_0_0.ysn.testnet
```

In this case, `share` is an `NFT` contract while `market` is an [open bids system](https://github.com/devey/YSN/discussions/21) plugged into it.
Different projects are deployed under `ysn.testnet` with the same pattern, and an `FT` contract is deployed at `ysn-1_0_0.ysn.testnet`.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this from one front-end without too many redirects, preferably one.
A thing that came to mind is to have a proxy contract that distributes the `Promise` requests to the set of contracts above; is that feasible, or might it have drawbacks?

Comment: you're talking about the redirects from NEAR Wallet when the user authorizes the 2 contracts?

Comment: Yes, @BenTheHumanMan, if you have multiple contracts under the same front-end, if you try to call a contract method that reads or updates the state and targets multiple addresses, you end up with as many redirects as the number of contracts.

Comment: One method will target multiple contracts and it doesn't throw gas panics? Without knowing more about your setup, I would guess that it's a design issue. Users should only need to authorize the bidding contract then subsequent bids they make that would withdraw funds - https://berryclub.io/

Comment: how/why does it target other contracts?

Comment: I'm refactoring the front-end to handle multiple `nft` projects (each with their `market`) and, for example, if you want to build a feed that pulls tokens from all of the `nft` contracts (without having a back-end) you would be redirected.
Thanks for the support; I'll do some more reading tomorrow and see if it's a design issue on my side.

Comment: I wish I could be better help. Please post here once you find a solution. I would think the ft/nft contract calls could maybe just be proxied by the market contract so the user wallet only needs to authorize market which would call/sign the various  nft/ft contracts calls.

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up using `localStorage` to save `contractAddress` on sign in and sign out and having:

```
useEffect(switchProject, [router.asPath])
```

to sign out if the path is for a different project than the one signed in for.